Is it possible that a 240V wall heater is connected to one breaker?
I have an old wall mounted electric heater. It takes 240v.
I only see two wires that it’s connected to and at the breaker box it’s only connected to one breaker. The breaker that it’s on only has one switch. It’s not like a double breaker that I see for laundry dryers.
How is this 240v device only connected to a single breaker?
I 'know' this because that is the only breaker that causes my non-contact voltage detector to beep.
Updated




add a photo of  the breaker showing the wiring.

Some double breakers have only one switch.  Does the breaker have two screws with wires on them(like double breakers)?

@Jasen I'm showing the breaker...but not the wiring.  I'm not comfortable with removing the panel.

If the heater is 240v, then it is possible(but not in code) it is on two breakers(9 and 11), also possible the label is wrong/that is not the right breaker.  Does the heater work if 11 is turned off?

Have you actually measured 240V at the heater? It may actually be getting 120V from the single breaker, and producing 1/4th as much heat as it’s designed to produce on 240V.

@crip659 When 11 is off, the non-contact voltage sensor is silent.

@nobody I haven’t tested the voltage. It would require me to disassemble the heater I think

Easy way to check: shut off all breakers but 11, see if it still heats. If so, it sure seems like it's only getting 120V from one breaker. If it doesn't, try turning on the other breakers one at a time to see what's going on.

seeing as you havrn't checked inside the box, it could be that this breaker powers the thermostat and a different breaker actually powers the heater.

I just added some wiring diagrams. Breaker is the ONLY breaker, when off, silences the voltage detector.

Voltage detectors are flaky and weird. Don't check what it does to the voltage detector, check what it does to the heater.

"Is it possible?" Of course it is! It might not function as expected, but just about anything is possible...

Two big issues to investigate. First is there a wall thermostat (or j-box where one might have been), it is legal in certain situations to use a thermostat that disconnects only one leg of 240v.  If the stat is off, failed or removed you may only get voltage when one leg is energized. Second, remove panel cover and trace the wire on #11 to where it leaves the panel. Does it leave in conduit with multiple colored wires, or is it part of a 12/2 or 12/3 cable? Where to other wires terminate in panel? Are the wires connections involved all tight?

There's a possibility that one hot lead is connected to breaker 11 and the other to 13. Seeing the label between the two breakers is suggestive... That's not the right way to do it.

Many older 240V devices only have two wires.  Today they would have 3 with the 3rd one being a ground lead.  There is no need for the NEUTRAL for things like your electric hot water heater and so only 2 wires, HOT1 and HOT2 (usually black and red) are used.
Not all 240V breakers have two reset handles.  Some are designed that way but others have only a single.  But the key difference is that it should have TWO HOT connections on it instead of just one like the 120V breakers have.  Depending on the design of the panel, they are usually twice as wide so they can connect to both of the HOT planes in the panel.

Black and red cables are usually only used if it needs neutral.  Most people will cheap out and use white for the second hot, use a /2 cable instead of a /3 cable.  Conduits must use hot colours.

The OP's breaker is single-width :/

single width, and it also has "1 pole" written on the label

Since I moved in we have never used the heater. Also we’ve upgraded the panel bc the previous one was really old and potentially a fire hazard.  I will try to unmount the heater and take voltage readings at the wires.
Will try voltage between wire 1 and 2. Then voltage between 1 and ground(it it’s connected). Then voltage between 2 and ground.  Does that sound correct?

@milesmeow: Yes, that will confirm whether you really have 240V or 120.
